# How to connect mysql in lambda nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, aws-lambda

How to connect mysql in lambda nodejs

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'root',
            password: '1304',
            database: 'DemoDB'
        })

        connection.connect(function (err) {
            if (!err) {
                console.log("Database connected ... ");
            }
            else {
                console.log("Error connecting database : " + err.message);
            }
        });

        const sql = "CREATE TABLE MESSAGE (message VARCHAR(255))";
        connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Table created");
        });
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current connection?

Comment: Error connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3307

Comment: Is your mysql on port `3307`? I thought the default port is `3306`. If you're using a different port, you must specify it in you connection like `port : '3307'` etc. If not, it will try to connect to the default port. Maybe you might as well just put `port: 3306` in the connection just to be sure.

Comment: `var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'root',
    password: '1304',
    database: 'DemoDB',
    socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'
})`

Comment: But it not work

Answer (score 0):

If this MySQL server is installed locally in your computer then here's a few troubleshooting that you can try:

1. Make sure your mysql services is running.
2. Make sure you can connect to the mysql db using that host+port+user+password combination - test connect to it using command line or sql tools like SQLyog etc.
3. Make sure that the mysql program and port it's using not blocked by firewall - if you have a strict firewall then you possibly need to do firewall exception for `mysqld`, `mysqld-nt` and port `3306`.

To check what port is your MySQL running on, you have to look for `my.ini` or `my.cnf` file (usually located in `MySQL` folder or `MySQL/Data` folder). In that file you need to find `port=XXXX` and there are two of them. Make sure both values of `port=` are the same.

The idea here is first to make sure your MySQL server is up and running before connecting through `node.js` because judging from the error message that you've received, it seems like its not a problem from `node.js`.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda function runs on the cloud (some remote server) whereas you are providing `localhost` as the `Database host` which means that your `MySQL server` is running on your `PC` so that is why the connection is not establishing. You have to provide the `IP` of your PC instead of `localhost` for things to work properly.